# Inverse 4-parameters Cumulative Weibull Distribution

Tags: quantiles, weibull-distribution

May someone write the inverse of the FOUR-parameters Weibull cumulative distribution (percent point function), please? I am referring to the 4-parameters formula appearing in Sigmaplot.

Comment: There probably is no formula for the inverse.

Comment: Existing for the three-parameters distribution, I wonder if it also exists for the four-parameters one.